# I'm facing a error The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("postId")

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, methods

```
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return FutureBuilder(
         future: postsRef
             .document(userId)
             .collection("usersPosts")
             .document(postId)
             .get(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.hasData) {
             return circularProgress();
           }
           Post post = Post.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
           return Center(
             child: Scaffold(
               appBar: header(context, titleText: post.description),
               body: ListView(
                 children: [
                   Container(
                     child: post,
                   )
                 ],
               ),
             ),
           );
         },
       );
     }
```

also this my error

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#37f30):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("postId")

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> file:///D:/Flutter/KadShare/kadshare/lib/pages/post_screen.dart:18:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      DocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:29:42)
#2      new Post.fromDocument (package:kadshare/widgets/post.dart:34:18)
#3      PostScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:kadshare/pages/post_screen.dart:28:26)
#4      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:773:55)
```

My Post Class

```
      final String postId;
      final String ownerId;
      final String username;
      final String location;
      final String description;
      final String mediaUrl;
      final dynamic likes;
    
      Post({
        this.postId,
        this.ownerId,
        this.username,
        this.location,
        this.description,
        this.mediaUrl,
        this.likes,
      });
    
      factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return Post(
          postId: doc["postId"],
          ownerId: doc["ownerId"],
          username: doc["username"],
          location: doc["location"],
          description: doc["description"],
          mediaUrl: doc["mediaUrl"],
          likes: doc["likes"],
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `snapshot` is a Flutter `AsyncSnapshot`, specifically a `AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>`. When `snapshot.hasData` is true, that means the `DocumentSnapshot` exists.

But a `DocumentSnapshot` exists even when the underlying document doesn't exist in the database, so you also need to check if the `DocumentSnapshot` has data, which you do with [`DocumentSnapshot.exists`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html).

So your check then becomes:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.exists) {
```

So this change means the spinner will keep being rendered if the document doesn't exist.

Alternatively, you may want to render a different UI if the document doesn't exist:

```
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
   if (!snapshot.hasData) {
     return circularProgress();
   }
   if (!snapshot.data.exists) {
     return Text("Document does not exist");
   }
   Post post = Post.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
   return Center(
     child: Scaffold(
       appBar: header(context, titleText: post.description),
       body: ListView(
         children: [
           Container(
             child: post,
           )
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 },
```

Also see [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)

Answer (score 0):

Your `snapshot.data` is null;

Maybe change:

```
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
```

Comment: You should be passing  null value in here > `Post.fromDocument(snapshot.data)`; so if you are checking beforehand, it should not happen... not sure what else it could be

Comment: I thought maybe postId it's not same with firebase i checked but it's corret. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are working on fluttershare course app, in your activity feed page when you press show post function make sure you give userId your currentUser.id passing in a non-null value for the 'postId' parameter as shown here:

```
  showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          userId: currentUser.id,
          postId: postId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```