# Listening to Stream doesn't get same result as StreamBuilder with Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I'm using firebase and I have this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> qs = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("$mypath")
        .orderBy(order)
        .limit(10)
        .startAfterDocument(lastDoc)
        .snapshots();
```

When I pass `qs` to a StreamBuilder, the returned snapshot can do `snapshot.hasError`.

```
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: qs, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) ... // hasError works
        },
      )
```

However when I listen to the stream, things like hasError, hasData ..., are not recognized anymore

```
    qs.listen((event) {
      if (event.hasError) // error: The getter 'hasError' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'.
    });
```

I still can do `event.docs` and I get the data successfully, but I can't listen for errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `hasError` and `hasData` are properties defined on the [`AsyncSnapshot` object](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html), and only exist when you're inside the `StreamBuilder`, where it essentially wraps the state of the asynchronous operation. When you call `AsyncSnapshot.data` in your code, you get back the `QuerySnapshot` that encapsulates the data from Firebase.

When you listen to the stream yourself, there is no `AsyncSnapshot` and you start with a `QuerySnapshot`, which is a Firestore object defined [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html). As you can see, that doesn't have `hasError` or `hasData` as those are exposed different.

This is definitely initially confusing as there are quite a few types of snapshots involved here, so I recommend checking out [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)

Comment: Been using firebase for a year now and it's still definitely confusing! ... What I'm trying to do is get the data from a Repository class which only Bloc has access to, and feed the data to widgets as they are available. It's doable with `QuerySnapshot`, but I see no way to handle the errors now. Is it possible to do this, or should I get the data from widgets, and sync them with the Bloc?

Comment: Handling errors just works differently when you listen to the stream yourself. You can check for errors with `handleError` as far as I can tell: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-async/Stream/handleError.html

Comment: I added this `...snapshots().handleError( (e) => print("11111 $e")` but the function never executes. I guess firebase handles the errors internally (that's how there's `hasError` in AsyncSnapshot) and won't rethrow it for the `handleError` to listen to it.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this part, but this is how it is implemented (for Android, but all platforms work pretty much the same): https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/64ee628516af5399afd4e02bfb86862bc6452d6c/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/firestore/streamhandler/QuerySnapshotsStreamHandler.java#L36-L48 and then on the Flutter side: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart#L129-L162