# The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

After migrating to null safety getting error The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

**Code snippet where error is**

```
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: searchResultsFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {    //have error here
          User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
          UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
          searchResults.add(searchResult);
        });
        return ListView(
          children: searchResults,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

searchResultsFuture

```
  handleSearch(String query) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> users =
        usersRef.where("displayName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get();
    setState(() {
      searchResultsFuture = users;
    });
  }

  clearSearch() {
    searchController.clear();
  }
```

Comment: *"The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>"* - yes indeed [AsyncSnapschot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) does not have a field called `docs`

Comment: so what do i have to do to fix my code?

Comment: use `AsyncSnapshot.data` property

Comment: @pskink can you please tell how i can use `AsyncSnapshot.data` property here

Comment: what do you see if you call `print(snapshot.data)`? if it is not `null` then it has your data

Comment: it is null what change do I have to get data with my code?

Comment: add `print(snapshot)` then - it seems that `error` is set

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(ConnectionState.done, Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot', null, null)

Comment: so it is not `null` - it is `_JsonQuerySnapshot` which is a concrete implementation of [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) class

Comment: so how do i display my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snapshot` in your code is an [`AsyncSnapshot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html), which indeed doesn't have a `docs` child. To get the docs from Firestore, you need to use:

```
snapshot.data.docs
```

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [listening for realtime data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes), which contains an example showing this - and my answer here explaining all snapshot types: [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)

Comment: Thank you for providing those information's, but still i haven't  being able to fix my code I'm very new to flutter and don't know much on using these code, I'm just trying to learn them

Comment: I gathered as much, which is why I provided two links where you can find a deeper explanation and more example code. If you're having trouble making those work, edit your question to show what you've tried with the information/code from the answer and links.

Answer (score 1):

change like this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: searchResultsFuture,
      builder: (context, **AsyncSnapshot** snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> searchResults = [];
        **snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {** 
          User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
          UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
          searchResults.add(searchResult);
        });
        return ListView(
          children: searchResults,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

usually, it takes a few ms for data to retrieve so I tried this to
make sure my operations  are performed after data is retrieved

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Collectionreference
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> activitySnapshot) {
      if (activitySnapshot.hasError) {
        return  Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong'),
            );
      }
      if (activitySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
                child: SpinKitWave(
              color: constants.AppMainColor,
              itemCount: 5,
              size: 40.0,
            )));
      }
      if (!activitySnapshot.hasData || activitySnapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
        return Center(
              child: Text('Nothing to Display here'),
            );
      }
      if (activitySnapshot.hasData) {
         activitySnapshot.data.docs.forEach(doc=>{
            print(doc);
          })
      }
     }
   });
```

Comment: tried this but it does not fix my issue, still getting the same error, i have started getting this error only after migrating to null safety