# Understanding FirebaseFirestore Read Data example

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

On the Read Data example of Firestore [this link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) I don't understand why it is necessary to include de snapshot.hasData to prove that the document does not exist.

```
if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }
```

Comment: In addition to Victor's excellent answer, I recommend checking out this answer on the different types of snapshots you may encounter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [.hasData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html) is an [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) property that "returns whether [a] snapshot contains a non-null data value."
- [.exists](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/exists.html) is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) property that "returns true if the document exists."

So `.hasData` is called to be sure the `DocumentSnapshot` from Firestore is available (a `DocumentSnapshot` is returned whether or not the document exists) and `.exists` is called to figure out if the document does exists.