# Why document doesn't exist. But all time !snapshot.hasData is false

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I make sign up system and managing user information.

When sign-up, users are required to write user name, and it's stored in firestore.

User data are stored like this;

[image: Img]

And trying to get `userName` with the code;

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: users.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    print("${!snapshot.hasData} ${!snapshot.data!.exists}"); // always "false true"
    if (!snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return Text("Document does not exist");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data =
          snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return Text("User Name: ${data['userName']}");
    }

    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

However always `return Text("Document does not exist");` is called, and `userName` is not displayed.

Why doesn't `userName` returned? I searched for a misspelling but couldn't find it.
This issue has taken a lot of time today. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snapshot.data` that you are referring to is the `AsyncSnapshot` that is used to monitor the status of the asynchronous operation. Its `hasData` becomes true when the asynchronous operation has completed: so when it is done reading the `DocumentSnapshot` from the database.

To detect whether the `DocumentSnapshot` actually exists, you need to check its `exists` property.

A quick summary of common statuses:

| Object.property | Value | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AsyncSnapshot.hasData` | `false` | the asynchronous operation has either not yet completed, or did not result in a `DocumentSnapshot` (for example: if there was a network error). Calling `snapshot.data` will result in an error message. |
| `AsyncSnapshot.hasData` | `true` | the asynchronous operation has completed and you can safely call `snapshot.data` on it to get the `DocumentSnapshot`. |
| `DocumentSnapshot.exists` | `false` | the document you requested does not exist, and calling `document.data` on the snapshot will result in an error. |
| `DocumentSnapshot.exists` | `true` | the document you requested exists, and you can access its data. |

So your `!snapshot.hasData` will be false once the `AsyncSnapshot` is done loading the `DocumentSnapshot`. To determine whether the document actually exists, use `snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists`.

I also recommend checking out my explanation here of the various types of snapshots in Flutter code: [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I can't still understand why `DocumentSnapshot.exists` always `false`. I checked misspelling again and again, and It's exist in firestore fields.

Answer (score 1):

Miss to use `!` before `snapshot.hasData`

```
if (!snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
      return Text("Document does not exist");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, this `if` statement ignored but snapshot was really empty.
        `print("${!snapshot.hasData} ${!snapshot.data!.exists}");` result is `false true`.
Why I can't get data?

Comment: what about your document id?

Comment: It's user uid. doc() is equal to doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) so I wrote so.