# How to fetch data from realtime database in a simple way in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

currently i'm using firestore and realtime database at the same time. I set and retrieve from firestore in the most simplest and effective way in code and for realtime database i set data but i couldn't retrieve it in the same way that i do with firestore.
Summary i want to do the same thing which i do with firestore code in realtime database code.

Here is my code:

```
//Get data from Firestore 

Stream <DocumentSnapshot> getData() async*{
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; 
    yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).snapshots();
    }

//Return data in StreamBuilder (No lists or ListView.Builder needed here)

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        //--------------------------------------
        //These equations comes from Firestore
        //--------------------------------------

        int currentWater ()=>  snapshot.data['currentLitersAmount'];

        int remainingWater () => snapshot.data['currentLitersAmount'] <= snapshot.data['recomendedLitersAmount'] ? snapshot.data['recomendedLitersAmount'] - snapshot.data['currentLitersAmount'] : 0;
        
        double progress ()=> snapshot.data['currentLitersAmount'] / snapshot.data['recomendedLitersAmount'];
```

So how to do the same thing here for realtime database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of your `getData` function for Realtime Database would be:

```
Stream <Event> getData() async*{
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; 
    yield* FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child(user.uid).onValue();
}
```

And you can then get the `DataSnapshot` from each [`Event` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Event-class.html) in your UI building code.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      int currentWater ()=>  snapshot.data.snapshot.value['currentLitersAmount'];
      ...
```

If that `snapshot.snapshot` looks confusing, have a look at [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)

Comment: Actually it gave me an error in code to be exact in the second snapshot: here => snapshot.snashot.value, So i have tried snapshot.data.value but also it returned an error (Class 'Event' has no instance getter 'value'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Event'
Tried calling: value)

Comment: `onValue` returns an `Event`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onValue.html, so the `snapshot` is an [event object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Event-class.html), from which you should be able to get the value. That's why you need `snapshot.snapshot`.

Comment: You're 100% correct but here the issue is when i write the code it gave me an error line under: 1. Stream<Event>.... reference('users') <= red-line under 'users'. 2. StreamBuilder(.... snapshot.(snapshot) <= red-line under it

Comment: unfortunately i can't find a way to share screen shots here to show you exactly what is happening

Comment: If you want to share a screenshot of the error, edit your question to include that screenshot. But I think I see what's wrong there now, so updated the code in my answer. I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation handy, as it'll be a lot faster if you can look up such syntax problems yourself. https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/reference.html

Comment: It worked, firebase has changed the code to snapshot.data.snapshot.value[''], Thank you so much