# How can I receive data from firestore 2 collection using 2 streambuilder and Listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I have used 2 streambuilder and listviewbuilder. But why this error is shown and I,m confused this code will work properly? Please, anybody have their answer?

I used streambuilder and inside it used ListView.builder. It means, firstly receives data from firestore documents and after check 'if'  condition, then again I used another streambuilder, and inside it use Listview. But the Listview children show an error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZuc4.png).

I want to that, when if condition true then firstly receive the data from chats collection [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM4qw.png) after that again receive data from another Architecture collection [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1oCO.png)

Please help me for solve this problem.

Here is my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserModel _getCurrentUserData = new UserModel.fromMap(currentUserValue);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext, int index) {
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> docData =
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();

                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

                    if (docData["senderId"] == _getCurrentUserData.uid ||
                        docData["receiverId"] == _getCurrentUserData.uid) {
                      return docData['senderId'] == _getCurrentUserData.uid
                          ? StreamBuilder(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection(docData['receiverDept'])
                                  .doc(docData['receiverDept'])
                                  .collection(docData['receiverIdentity'])
                                  .where('uid',
                                      isEqualTo: docData['receiverId'])
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                  return Text("Loading...");
                                return ListView(
                                    children: snapshot.data!.docs <-- [show an Error][4]
                                        .map((Map<dynamic, dynamic> document) {
                                  return ListTile(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => chatPage3(
                                              targetUserValue: document,
                                              currentUserValue: currentUserValue),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    title: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Stack(
                                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional
                                                  .bottomEnd +
                                              AlignmentDirectional(-0.1, -0.3),
                                          children: [
                                            CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 30,
                                            ),
                                            senderStatus == 'Online'
                                                ? Container(
                                                    width: 12,
                                                    height: 12,
                                                    // alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        color: Colors.green,
                                                        shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                                  )
                                                : Container(),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              senderName,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontFamily: 'JosefinSans',
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              'Last Text',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'JosefinSans',
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                color: Colors.black54,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }));
                              })
                          : docData["receiverId"] == _getCurrentUserData.uid
                              ? StreamBuilder(
                                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection(docData['senderDept'])
                                      .doc(docData['senderDept'])
                                      .collection(docData['senderIdentity'])
                                      .where('uid',
                                          isEqualTo: docData['senderId'])
                                      .snapshots(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                      return Text("Loading...");
                                    return ListView(
                                        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                                            (Map<dynamic, dynamic> document) {
                                      return ListTile(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) => chatPage3(
                                                  targetUserValue: document,
                                                  currentUserValue: currentUserValue),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        title: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Stack(
                                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional
                                                      .bottomEnd +
                                                  AlignmentDirectional(
                                                      -0.1, -0.3),
                                              children: [
                                                CircleAvatar(
                                                  radius: 30,
                                                ),
                                                senderStatus == 'Online'
                                                    ? Container(
                                                        width: 12,
                                                        height: 12,
                                                        // alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                                        decoration:
                                                            BoxDecoration(
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .green,
                                                                shape: BoxShape
                                                                    .circle),
                                                      )
                                                    : Container(),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 10,
                                            ),
                                            Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  senderName,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily: 'JosefinSans',
                                                      fontSize: 20,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600),
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                  'Last Text',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily: 'JosefinSans',
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }));
                                  })
                              : Container();
                    }
                    return Container();
                  });
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('Document aren\'t availavle'),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Getting Error'),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot` object you have is an `AsyncSnapshot`, which doesn't have a `docs` property. To get to the docs, you'll want to get the `snapshot.data!.docs`.

Also see my explanation here of the various types of snapshots that are involved when you load data from Firebase in Flutter: [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase/65874916#65874916)