# how to check if Firestore doc exists?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been fetching a post and in my Forestore i have a collection with the name `likes` and in this collection i have stored docs with all users email. then i've created a nested collection 'liked' and in this i have a doc with post id's in which that user liked.

so to get these i've created a `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("likes")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth
          .instance.currentUser!.email)
      .collection("liked")
      .doc(id)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    bool liked = false;

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var col = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("likes");

      var doc = col.doc(FirebaseAuth
          .instance.currentUser!.email);

      var col2 = doc.collection("liked");

      var doc2 = col2.doc(id).get();

      if (doc2 == null) {
        liked = false;
      } else {
        liked = true;
      }
    }
    return Row(
      children: [
        // Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
        IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              liked
                  ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("likes")
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .currentUser!.email)
                      .delete()
                  : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("likes")
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .currentUser!.email)
                      .collection("liked")
                      .add({"like": true});
            },
            icon: GradientIcon(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              icon: liked
                  ? CupertinoIcons.heart_fill
                  : CupertinoIcons.heart,
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.deepPurple,
                    Colors.deepPurpleAccent
                  ]),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }),
```

in the above code i was trying to check if the user liked that specific post and change the ui accordingly. but i think the keyWord `exist` has been deprecated so whenever i try to check if the doc exists it always returns true b/c the snapshot always has data.

so how can i check if the doc exists by using the doc id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your code first loads the data into a `StreamBuilder, but then in there goes back to the database to load the same data again.

Instead of that, get the data from the snapshot with:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("likes")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth
          .instance.currentUser!.email)
      .collection("liked")
      .doc(id)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
    bool liked = false;

    if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
      var docSnapshot = asyncSnapshot.data!;

      liked = !docSnapshot.exists;
    }
    ...
```

Since some of your confusion likely comes from the different types of snapshots involved, I recommend also reading my answer to [What is the difference between existing types of snapshots in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874202/what-is-the-difference-between-existing-types-of-snapshots-in-firebase).

Comment: do you mean instead of `StreamBuilder`?